# When using the siam optimization class file, \tag is not working because of math mode - yet it's surrounded by dollar signs?

Tags: tag

```
% SIAM Article Template
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart220329}


%%% commands and packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\title{a}
\author{a}
\date{}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
a
\end{abstract}


\begin{keywords}
a
\end{keywords}


\begin{MSCcodes}
a
\end{MSCcodes}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\label{teg:a}\tag{$\mathscr{A}_A$}
5x = 26
\end{equation}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{siamplain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this is latex I get the error: "LaTeX Error: \mathscr allowed only in math mode" but clearly it IS in math mode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you get no error from that in `article` where is `siamart220329.cls` from?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danoan/gf-paper/master/SIAM/siamart220329.cls

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's the style class file for the journal SIAM optimization. I'm not sure what you mean when you write "you get no error from that in article".

Comment: I initally tested article class as the siam one is not in texlive

Comment: Off topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`.  No need to do it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class patches `equation` I did not trace exactly what it is doing but

```
\tag{\mbox{$\mathscr{A}_A$}}
```

works

[image]

Comment: This fixed it, thanks a lot for your help!